External Monitor not always chosen as 1st option
I have my Lenovo LOQ 15 laptop connected via Display port to a QHD external monitor. In Windows 11 Display Settings I have 'show only on 2' selected, however sometimes it mirrors the laptop's 1080 screen and both are on displaying at the laptop's 1080 native resolution. At that point I have to manually re-set my settings back to "show only on 2" again in order to get the correct screen and resolution.
Other settings I have enabled are 'remember windows locations' and 'make this my main display', but the issues still occur. I've also tried disabling the laptop screen in device manager but again to no avail.
Is there a way around this?!

Could you perhaps add some periods to break up this run-on sentence? I think that may help make this question more clear. Have you checked for and updated video drivers and system firmware? What is your laptop model?

Ok I've changed a few commas into periods, hope that makes things clearer...laptop is a Lenovo LOQ 15, all drivers and firmware are up to date.

Please observe how I had edited your post. Please note that all information needs to be in the question itself, not down here in the comments. Please read the HELP section to better understand how this site works and how to write questions that will be well received.

Thanks for the lesson on how to formally pose questions, I look forward to hearing from someone who might have an answer to the now thankfully clear issue.
